# Java methods synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronize

I need some help with my first synchronization task at university. We need to code a class "Communicator" with a given Interface Receiver and the method *private void receive(String message)* to receieve messages.
Communicator should be able to sign up receievers, without signing up the same Receiver twice. send a message to one or to all Receiver. All three methods need to be synchronized so that eg sendall is finished before a new message can be sent to a new Receiver. My idea was following code.

```
package threads;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import threads.geg.Receiver;

public class Communicator {
    private Map<String,Receiver> rec;
    public Communicator(){
        this.rec = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String signUp(Receiver aReceiver){
        synchronized(this.rec){ 
            if(rec.containsValue(aReceiver)){
                Set<String> k = rec.keySet();
                for(String i :k){
                    if(rec.get(i).equals(aReceiver))
                        return i;
                }
            }
            else{   
                String s = "Rec-"+rec.size();
                rec.put(s,aReceiver);                   
                return s;                       
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void send(String identifier, String message){
        if(rec.containsKey(identifier)){
            synchronized(this.rec){ 
                this.rec.get(identifier).receive(message);  
            }
        }else{
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid identifier!");
        }
    }
    public void sendAll(String message){
        synchronized(this.rec){ 
            Set<String> t = rec.keySet();
            for(String i:t){
                rec.get(i).receive(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't quite work. I've researched many hours about synchronisation but i can hardly find anything to solve my problem. Maybe someone of you can help me.

Comment: Please give more details on "doesn't quite work". Under what conditions does it not work, and how does the "does not work" manifest itself?

Comment: There is an automated controlling system which checks the code and says that may solution is wrong and the test cases imply that my codes messes up when multiple threads try to signUp, send or sendAll

Comment: *that my solution

Comment: not quite sure if the posted code works at all with/without the `synchronized` on the list..... anyways , regarding your comments , when your saying , multiple threads , do you have any clue if they are calling your class with new? because you class does not look like a singleton and if for each thread , there is assigned one new instance of `Communicator` then the `synchronized` keyword is useless. Reading this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/multi-threading/thread-synchronization-object-level-locking-and-class-level-locking/) might be usefull

Comment: What does the `Receiver` interface look like?  Seems like `rec` should be a `Map<String, Receiver>`, with the `String` key is the `identifier`.  Synchronize on `rec` and remove the names and queues `ArrayList`s.

Comment: I really don't know to be true but the task says explicit that the class Communicator has to synchronise the methods signUp, send and sendAll so that each method has finished before another thread can execute the method.

Comment: The specification only says that the Interface Reciever has the method receive(String message) which allows a Reciever to receive a message.

Comment: Synchronize on `rec` **within** each method, so when a method is invoked from another thread that other thread will wait until `rec` is available.

Comment: So I don't need any wait or notify at all?

Comment: Correct - when one thread exits the synchronized block another thread will be able to enter the synchronized block.  There's no need for wait/notifyAll.

Comment: As you can see in my original post i've updated my code but the automated checking client from my university still says that it is incorret. Can you spot any problems? Maybe it's because it says if a sendAll thread is waiting no send should be able to get active? Thanks for your help.